# copy spreadsheet without the form

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new bee trying to use google app scripts.
I am trying to copy spreadsheet using

var copySheet=spreadSheetCurrent.copy(date.toString('yyyy-MM-dd'));

this is also making a copy of the form associated with this spreadsheet, can I just copy only the spreadsheet ?

Comment: You can create an empty one and copy all its data. Is it ok to you? If is I will post an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy with this script:

```
function doCopy() {
  var srcSpread = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AkkQD4hSd4KAdEdyZHM4Xzd3QjMwdDVxazVLOTBFN2c");
  var destSpread = SpreadsheetApp.create("Copy of Plan X");

  for(var idx in srcSpread.getSheets()) {
    srcSpread.getSheets()[idx].copyTo(destSpread);
  }
}
```

Shared [here](https://script.google.com/d/1bNpbQEPxDejIytHkt_QkfojhlsHpvy6f1VfCGUVRxekw92Lg7awu3pzj/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: The main problem I see here is that it creates the new spreadsheet in the root of your Drive. Google needs to implement a method that allows creating a spreadsheet in a specific folder.